# How to receive UDP Webcam stream continuously?

Tags: java, udp, webcam

Server

```
try {
        DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(4242);
    
    
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);

        WebcamPanel panel = new WebcamPanel();

        JFrame window = new JFrame("Test webcam panel");
        window.add(panel);
        window.setSize(500, 500);
        window.setResizable(true);
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setVisible(true);
        
        while(true){
            socket.receive(packet);
            System.out.println("received");
            byte[] buff = packet.getData();
            ByteArrayInputStream bain = new ByteArrayInputStream(buff);
            panel.DrawImage(ImageIO.read(bain));
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Client

```
try{
        DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket();
        InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName("localhost");
        
        Webcam webcam = Webcam.getDefault();
        webcam.setViewSize(WebcamResolution.VGA.getSize());
        
        WebcamPanel panel = new WebcamPanel(webcam);
        panel.setFPSDisplayed(true);
        panel.setDisplayDebugInfo(true);
        panel.setImageSizeDisplayed(true);
        panel.setMirrored(true);

        JFrame window = new JFrame("Test webcam panel");
        window.add(panel);
        window.setResizable(true);
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.pack();
        window.setVisible(true);

        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        
        while(true){
            ImageIO.write(webcam.getImage(),"jpg", baos);
            baos.flush();
            byte[] image_buffer = baos.toByteArray();
            System.out.println(image_buffer.length);
            DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(image_buffer, image_buffer.length, address, 4242);
            socket.send(packet);
            
        }
        
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.toString();
    }
```

console->client :

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
20884
41796
62687
83582
```

console->server :

```
received
received
received
```

Server can't receive a whole data. And It received three data and stopped. I can't understand why Server stopped. Webcampanel in Client is checking webcam to. It works well, but can't send Image. How to receive whole data continuously? please find problem.

Answer (score 0):

You declare a package of `1024 bytes`

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
```

In your server, you're reading each package and treat it as a whole Image:

```
byte[] buff = packet.getData(); // This is not a whole image yet
ByteArrayInputStream bain = new ByteArrayInputStream(buff);
panel.DrawImage(ImageIO.read(bain));
```

For example, first Image has length of `20884` so it takes at least `20884/1024 + 1` packages to reconstruct the image.

If you check server log I think you'll see some kind of runtime exception when the Image is not fully constructed and used to draw to the pane.

In order to receive the whole packages and reconstruct the image, you need to know how to detect end of file at the server.

But technically, UDP protocol is unreliable, you can missing some packages, your received packages order would not be as same as when it's sent. So it's very hard to do it with UDP.

I suggest using TCP for file transfering. It's reliable, packages order is guaranteed.

Comment: Thank you for answer. but I don't know how to fix my source

Comment: Send "end" after I send Image?

Comment: Use TCP instead. UDP does not guarantee that your `"end"` package will be received in server side. So you can't detect end of file in your server.

Comment: I want make UDP Server, Because TCP was very slow. I don't care, several data missed.

Comment: TCP is slower than UDP, yes. But it does not slow enough for you to abandon it. If some package of image data is missed, you cannot reconstruct your image again.

Answer (score 0):

Just change this

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    while(true){
        ImageIO.write(webcam.getImage(),"jpg", baos);
        baos.flush();
        byte[] image_buffer = baos.toByteArray();
        // ...
   }
```

to this:

```
    while(true){
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ImageIO.write(webcam.getImage(),"jpg", baos);
        baos.flush();
        byte[] image_buffer = baos.toByteArray();
        // ....
    }
```

this works for me.